# How to pass signal to Spark that R code has completed the process and generated csv file?

Tags: r, apache-spark, signals, integration

I want to integrate R code with Spark. I am successful in integration. Post this integration, my R code will generate an csv file which would be input for rest of the Spark code. Here, I want to pass signal to Spark that, my R process has completed and start Spark code processing. Could you please help me with the R code for the same?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Spark's capabilities in this regard, but perhaps it would be possible to write a simple bash script that 1. Checks whether the file exists. 2. If the file exists, kick off the Spark job.  You could then schedule this check to be executed periodically using `crontab`.

Comment: I don't want to hit periodically. Is there any way to signal to Spark?

Comment: I don’t have much experience with spark outside of sparkSQL and the sparkR API. I suspect there is an answer to your question, but it might take some reframing to find- perhaps eliminating the constraint that R must pass the signal, and trying to understand the basics of spark IO might help you to understand _what_ signal needs to be passed. Then, I have no doubt that R can pas that signal once you know what it is.